# JPA Criteria Join did not give me a list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

Hello I'm doing an advanced search query using Criteria and I have something like this

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

    Root<Event> eventRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Event.class);

    Join<Event,Community> communityJoin = eventRoot.join("community", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Event,User> user = eventRoot.join("user", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Event,Device> device = eventRoot.join("device", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Event,List<AuditLog>> auditLogs = eventRoot.join("auditLogs", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I have as you can see one-to-many relation with AuditLog entity (mapped as auditLogs). Then I'm doing the selection like this

```
    selections.add(user.alias("user"));
    selections.add(device.alias("device"));
    selections.add(auditLogs.alias("auditLogs"));
```

I'm getting the result as a Tuple List

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Tuple> tuples = (List<Tuple>) query.getResultList();
```

The problem is that whem I'm getting auditLogs from the tuple I'm getting it like AuditLog object instead of List of AuditLog

```
    tuples.get(0).get("auditLogs")
```

Am I doing something wrong?. I don't know why I can't have a result as a List AuditLog.

Comment: you will get list of tuples of size N where N is the number of actual SQL rows returned by query. So you will get single entry per tuple. Root will be present multiple times, etc.

Comment: I got a List of tuple like this List<Tuple<Key, Value>> right?. The "value" field of the tuple element cannot be a List?

Comment: Its just mapping SQL row into entity, not aggregating them (not grouping)